# How to know if my AWS role has IAMFullAccess?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, credentials, aws-secrets-manager, credential-manager

I'm currently working on a task to configure credential rotation in AWS Secret Manager, I did some reading, from my understanding, the best practice is to use the feature on Secret Manager Console 'enable the rotation', then SM will create a Lambda function and perform the rotation on a schedule that we defined (e.g. rotate every 30 days etc), but it seems like it requires `IAMFullAccess` role to configure this, my question is how can I check if my current AWS account has the full access or does it mean I must use root account to configure this? Many thanks.

Comment: Go to the IAM console. Can you list the policies attached to you (if you are an IAM user) or to the IAM role that you assumed (if you are a federated/SSO user)?

Comment: I'm in a developer role, just wondering if I must have a root user role to configure the rotation? @jarmod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need root access to configure Secrets Manager key rotation. As a general rule, you should [disable root access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_root-user.html) once you've set up appropriate IAM users. There are very [few tasks that actually require root access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_tasks-that-require-root.html).

To check your IAM policies, go to the IAM Console and list the policies attached to you (if you are an IAM user and/or in an IAM group) or to the IAM role that you assumed (if you are a federated/SSO user). If you can't access these IAM resources then you don't have full IAM access.

Note that you don't necessarily need to have the managed policy named `IAMFullAccess`, though that's commonly a way used to give you the relevant IAM permissions. You essentially need the permissions that that managed policy gives you (which is `iam:*` on all resources).